# Scheduling algorithms in linux kernel

Tags: linux, process, kernel, scheduling

How many different algorithms are implemented in the linux kernel? Are there only FIFO and Round Robin, or are there any other?

Where can I found a good documentation on this topic?

Let's say if I wanted to implement these algorithms myslef, where should I start?

Comment: best way to learn it : read kernel codes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In terms of real-time schedulers, linux provides FIFO and Round-Robin (POSIX `SCHED_FIFO` and `SCHED_RR`).  There is also a time-sharing scheduler called the [Completely Fair Scheduler (CFS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_Fair_Scheduler), which is complex enough that you might call it multiple schedulers (i.e., multi-core, and several styles/flavors of preemption for different loads).  CFS is described in some detail in the kernel documentation ([sched-design-CFS](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/scheduler/sched-design-CFS.txt)) but a careful read of the relevant sources is recommended.  CFS is linux's implementation of POSIX's `SCHED_OTHER` policy.

Additionally, there are patches that add other scheduling policies like [a new real-time Earliest Deadline First (EDF) scheduler](http://www.evidence.eu.com/sched_deadline.html).

Apart from a number of books on the topic, many of which are immediately out of date at publication time, you can refer to the [kernel documentation here](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/scheduler/) or in your kernel tree under docs/scheduler.  It's also useful to peruse the [LKML archives for discussion on the topic](http://marc.info/?l=linux-kernel&w=2&r=1&s=scheduler&q=b).

If you are just getting started or want to play with a wider range of real-time schedulers, you might consider UNC's [LITMUS-RT framework](http://www.litmus-rt.org/).

Comment: Books - pre-printed web-pages.  You gotta laugh :-)

Comment: @BlankXavier: Particularly ironic on the "real-time" topic.